# Difference between "山を登ったり、降りたり...." and "山を登って、降りて..."

Tags: grammar, translation, verbs

What are the differences in meaning between:

1. "山を登ったり、降りたり、よく考えた。"
2. "山を登ってって、降りてって、よく考えた。"
3. "山を登って、降りて、よく考えた。"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "山を登ったり、降りたり、よく考えた。" is an unnatural sentence. If it's something like 山を登ったり、降りたり、よく遊んだ, you can interpret that the concrete actions of playing include climbing or descending a mountain. Or, if it's 山を登ったり、降りたり、よく考えたりした, it means that you did many things including climbing and descending a mountain or thinking profoundly.
2. "山を登ってって、降りてって、よく考えた。" is a contraction of …登って行って、降りて行って…, i.e. "I went on climbing a mountain, went on descending and thought of it profoundly", where you take these actions in this order.
3. "山を登って、降りて、よく考えた。" means that you climbed and descended a mountain, then thought.

Answer (score 1):

In brief, my feelings on the topic:

1. On occasions when scaling, on occasions when descending...
2. While climbing and while descending..
3. Climbing up, climbing down ..

たり is most commonly used for expressing variety in actions that are not necessarily related.

ってって, presumably a shortening of the present+future gerund (te-iru), is used in explaining what happened during a duration (and only during that period).

~て the gerund form is actually very versatile and here might mean "climbing, descending, I mulled it over deeply."

The differences in meaning are slight but those are essentially the rules I know and have absorbed through years of study and some trips abroad to Japan.  Perhaps a more fluent expert would be able to clarify your question to a greater degree.

Comment: no. I'm pretty sure #1 does not deal with frequency. It carries another meaning that I can't quite articulate. I don't think a native speaker would stack present continuous on top of present continuos (like #2) not the least because it is a mouthful to say. And, a "gerund" is when a present participle is used as a noun. In this case, the present participle is used as a verb (in the present continuous tense). #1 (probably) sounds the most natural, but why? It's driving me crazy.